# UIView container to autoscroll on keyboard resize

Tags: iphone, uiview, keyboard

I have a `UIViewController`, it's a view (`UIView`) containing two elements - `UIPageControl` and also a `UIScrollView`. Now, when using normal keyboard, the view is a perfect fit, sharing the screen with the keyboard. But when an international keyword is used, the keyboard would add an extra ribbon for showing the international characters. When that's happened, the view would be covered by the extra keyboard ribbon. The view can't be resized as the `UIScrollView` view contains a table of two rows of fixed size. So now I am wondering if I should find a way to allow the `UIView` container to up shift to accommodate the ribbon and shift back when the ribbon disappears. Or is there any other better solutions to work around the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer to this stackoverflow post here: [detect the appear and disappear of international keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073795/detect-the-appear-and-disappear-of-international-keyboard/9073906#9073906)

Basically, you'll want to sign up to receive notifications about when the keyboard is shown.  From there you can get the keyboard frame size and then adjust views in your window to display properly.  The tutorials in the post really do a good job explaining how to do this.  Check them out!  If you still have questions I can try to help you with specifics.